# How are floating point array indices interpreted?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, floating-point

I can't find any information on this, but suppose I have

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var x = arr[1.5];
```

I assumed that Javascript would `floor` the index and returns the item at index 1, but it seems at least in Chrome it just returns `undefined`.

Is this correct?  I can't find any standard or documentation that confirms this.  It's actually really inconvenient if so because I assumed the round-down behavior allows you to pass any float in the range [0, n) to an array index, but it seems you'll silently break your arrays if you do floating point math which isn't rounded.

*Edit: if anyone's maintaining a list of javascript gotchas, please add this one.  Now I have to review 10k lines of javascript code to see where this assumption I made is quietly causing bugs!*

Comment: FWIW this how `obj[...]` is evaluated: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.2.1

Comment: I think that this section is more relevant: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [MDN: Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), array items are actually properties, and properties are identified by strings.

Accessing `arr[1.5]` is therefore the same as accessing `arr['1.5']`, and Firefox does actually do it that way.

This code:

```
var x = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

x[1.5] = 42;

alert(x);
alert(x['1.5']);
alert(x['1.50']);
```

outputs:

```
 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
 42
 undefined
```

So, the item accessed using a floating point value is a property identified by the string representation of the number. Note that accessing an item using `'1.50'` is not the same as accessing an item using `'1.5'`, so the index is not converted to a number.

I tested this in Internet Explorer and Chrome also, and they both do the same as Firefox.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why you think Chrome would "round" or "floor" the value when accessing an `Array`, but it doesn't do that at all. Neither does Firefox. It's just accessing a "key" which is not there and both browsers correctly return the `undefined` value (at least in the latest versions which I'm testing on).
Since `Arrays` are also `Objects` in ECMAscript, you're just accessing the value behind the keyname `1.5`.

I really think I should point that out a little more. An `Array` is just an `Object` (it also inherits from `Object`) with a `.length` property and a few added methods. There is no numerical array-access like in C/C++. Its just accessing a keyname of an object.

```
var foo = [1,2,3];

foo instanceof Array; // true;
foo instanceof Object; // true;
```

Comment: There *could* still be optimizations for arrays in an implementation though (in whatever way).

Comment: @FelixKling: of course. But that is not the question what happens under the hood. I just explained how Javascript behaves here.

Comment: I see, I guess coming from a C++ background I had assumed in my head that arr[f] implicitly converts f to an integer.  Ouch.

Answer (score 6):

That's expected, since js converts the index into a string and accesses the object property (since object property indexes are always strings), so it'll actually look up `arr['1.5']`

For those non-believers, the relevant part of [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) is 15.4 which clearly defines array index as a string.

Comment: Is there really a rule in javascript that says "if the array index is a whole number, leave it as a number, but if it's not a whole number, convert it to a string"?

Comment: @AshleysBrain: There is no real numerical array access in ecmascript. Those "numbers" are also just object keys as I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: @AshleyBrains. No, indexes are **always** converted to strings before lookup. For example `a=[42]; a['0']` evaluates to `42`.

Comment: @AshleyBrain: Actually they are all accessed as strings, so accessing `arr[1]` is the same as `arr['1']`. There is however some "magic" in `length` and `toString`, so that they only consider items that are whole numbers.

Comment: I knew javascript was mad, but... array indices are all strings...?  *head explodes*

Comment: @AshleysBrain: I wouldn't say it like that. Again, Arrays are just `Objects` with a `.length` property and some special methods added.

Comment: @AshleysBrain, shouldn't be such a big deal, why can't you just do `arr[Math.floor(x)]`?

Comment: @davin I'm not sure. I think that `'0'` is converted to `0` in your example.

Comment: @AshleysBrain: Have a look at the link I posted to your question (especially step 6).

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = "hello";
alert(arr["0"]);
Output : hello
```

In JavaScript, whenever indexing an array element the index is converted by the JavaScript interpreter into a string which it then uses as a key. This is the same as using a key-value pair Hash Map in java.

```
arr[5-"5"]
```

In this case the mathematical expression is evaluated first and the result is converted to a string and used as the key. This is how it works:

<1> The interpreter converts "5" into an integer since "-" operator cannot be used with strings and then subtracts it from the left operand 5 to get the result 0.

<2> The result is then converted to string and used as the key.