# JavaScript: Math.random() returning the same numbers. How do I stop this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random, web-frontend

I have an array of JavaScript strings, and I want to pick a random string from the array. However, when it runs in Edge and Chrome, it doesn't throw any errors, but it picks the same strings from the array every time. I have looked at other answers on Stack Overflow, but none of them seemed to help. Here is my code:

```js
var arr = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6", "string7"]; /* 100 quotes in the real array. */
var dis = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of strings you would like to display."));

if(dis > arr.length) {
    alert("You have entered a number that is too great.");
} else {
    for(var n = 1; n <= dis; n++) {
        document.write(arr[(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1))] + "<br/>");      
    } 
}
```

Anyone have any code snippets that work for making sure it doesn't pick the same strings?

Comment: `var arr = ["string1,` <-- error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are floating point array indices interpreted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649283/how-are-floating-point-array-indices-interpreted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an int for the index by rounding down with `Math.floor()`.

```js
var arr = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6", "string7"]; /* 100 quotes in the real array. */
var dis = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of strings you would like to display."));

if(dis > arr.length) {
    alert("You have entered a number that is too great.");
}
else {
    for(var n = 1; n <= dis; n++) {
        document.write(arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)] + "<br/>");      
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is because you need to cast Math.random to an integer.
Try this.

`document.write(arr[parseInt((Math.random()*(arr.length-1)))]+"<br/>");`

Comment: `parseInt` is for converting a string to an integer. The more typical approach is `Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

//////////////

```
document.write(arr[getRandomInt(0, arr.length-1)]+"<br/>");
```